# Get rows based on a condition that is dependent on the table and not solely on the row

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table with two (indexed) columns: document IDs and the words the document contains.

```
____________________
__docID__|__Word___|
    1    |    it   |
    1    |  rains  |
    2    |  this   |
    2    |    is   |
    2    |  cold   |
    3    |    it   |
    3    |    is   |
    3    | snowing |
```

So there are three documents represented in the table:
`it rains`, `this is cold`, `it is snowing`

How I can get the table efficiently that contains all the rows of those documents that contain a certain word, let's say `Word = 'it'`:

```
____________________
__docID__|__Word___|
    1    |    it   |
    1    |  rains  |
    3    |    it   |
    3    |    is   |
    3    | snowing |
```

Can the query be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (docID = this.docID, Word = 'it') is in table
```

Comment: Can it be done in a single SELECT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

```
select 
* 
from 
`some_table` 
where `docID` in (select `docID` from `some_table` where `Word` = 'it');
```

Comment: @Strawberry we can indeed achieve same thing using joins as well.

Comment: How would you do it with joins given that documents may contain different number of words.

Comment: @FiboKowalsky probably something like this.

`select 
main.* 
from 
some_table main, some_table sub on main.docID = sub.docID and sub.Word = 'it';`